# Angular toggle color of specific span

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a mat-table with which I am dynamically adding columns to and populating. The headers of this table consist of several divs and spans to format them specifically. When I click a header, I want its color to change to black, but when I click another header, I want the previous to revert and the new header to change color.

Currently, I can get it to toggle a header, but don't know how to make it untoggle another header. Earlier I was running into an issue where if I clicked one span, I toggled all of them. I fixed this by only toggling a span based on its ID.

Here is what I have so far in the HTML:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.columnName1}}" *ngFor = "let column of displayColumns">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            <div *ngIf = "column.stackedHeader">
              <div [ngStyle] = "{'color': (column.toggled) ? 'black' : 'grey'}" (click) = "toggleColumn($event)" class = "column-header" id = "{{column.columnName1}}">
                {{ column.columnHeader1 }}
              </div>
              <div (click) = "toggleColumn($event)" class = "column-header" id = "{{column.columnName2}}">
                {{ column.columnHeader2 }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf = "!column.stackedHeader" (click) = "toggleLocationColumn($event)" class = "column-header" id = "{{column.columnName1}}">
              {{column.columnHeader1}}
            </div>
          </th>
```

```
toggleColumn($event) {
    const columnId = $event.toElement.id;
    this.columnToggled.emit($event);
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.displayColumns.length; i++) {
      if (columnId === this.displayColumns[i].columnName1) {
        this.displayColumns[i].toggled = !this.displayColumns[i].toggled;
      }
    }
  }
```

And finally, here is an example of the array with which I am using to populate the table:

```
[{
    columnName1: 'Pickup',
    columnHeader1: 'Pickup',
    columnName2: 'Delivery',
    columnHeader2: 'Delivery',
    stackedHeader: true,
    stackedRow: true,
    toggled: false
  },
  {
    columnName1: 'FromCity',
    columnHeader1: 'From',
    columnName2: 'ToCity',
    columnHeader2: 'To',
    stackedHeader: true,
    stackedRow: true,
    toggled: false
  }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to see the big picture, some parts are missing, but here are some refactor suggestions to make the code less error prone.

When defining the click handlers in the template, you don't have to pass the `$event`, you can pass any variable in defined in the template.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.columnName1}}" *ngFor = "let column of displayColumns">
        <!-- ... -->
            <!-- see the toggleColumn call below, and the missing `id` attribute -->
            <div ... (click) = "toggleColumn(column)" class = "column-header" >
        <!-- ... -->
```

So then you don't receive the DOM element, but the actual business object. That also let's you use types. With that, you don't need the `id` on the clicked DOM element either.
The `toggleColumn` is a bit convoluted.
First, the `for-i` is very error prone, you should use `forEach`, and also makes the code more readable because of the less array reference. I rewrote the method like this:

```js
toggleColumn(selectedColumn: Column) {
    this.columnToggled.emit($event);
    this.displayColumns.forEach((otherColumn: Column) => {
        otherColumn.toggled = otherColumn.id === selectedColumn.id;
    });
  }
```

And now that I think, your problem might be that you only change the `toggled` field for the selected column, not the others, see the `if` criteria:

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= this.displayColumns.length; i++) {
    if (columnId === this.displayColumns[i].columnName1) {
        this.displayColumns[i].toggled = !this.displayColumns[i].toggled;
    }
}
```

The simplest solution might be that you remove the `if` from the statement above, and negate the `toggled` on all of the columns.

Comment: Thanks a ton! You're right about `forEach`, i just have a habit of using `for-i`. In the function call, I ended up passing the object to the function and set all `column.toggled` to `false` and then after set `selectedColumn.toggled` to `true`.